# Gitlab: how to allow user to create project under a group namespace

Tags: gitlab

Some users of the gitlab server are registered as developer under a given group. I would like these users to be able to create repositories under the namespace of the group.
As currently set, the users do not even have the "Namespace" field under the "Project path" field when creating new projects.
Is this possible ?

Comment: I am a user with admin privileges, but even I cannot create a project under a group.  As far as I can tell the project developers have gone out of their way to make this very hard to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1st option you have is to change by yourself the namespace after the developer created the project:

```
project -> settings/gear icon -> edit project -> transfer project
```

2nd possible thing is to edit [project_security_spec.r](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/spec/models/project_security_spec.rb)b or [ability.rb](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/app/models/ability.rb) 
(i'm not familiar with that good enough to explain more...)

Comment: 2nd thing means patching gitlab, right? Or is this configuration?

Comment: I don't think so - ability.rb is in app/models - so clearly not configuration. About the spec I am not sure though - isn't that just the test against the model? Does editing it influence anything?

Answer (score 0):

You could create an external service that uses the GitLab API to create the project. Using this method, you also have the chance to directly initialize the project with a README and so on.

Answer (score 0):

(Don't know about the GitLab Version for this question is very old - but I came here with the same problem - so here is the answer for today)

Give the users the role "Maintainer" -> see: https://gitlab.com/help/user/permissions